# too many characters in character literal - passing string to a onclick razor object

Tags: razor, blazor

This is the code

```
<MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.SwipeRight"
               Variant="Variant.Outlined" Color="Color.Primary"
               Size="Size.Small" 
               OnClick="()=>TaskComplete(task,"InProgress")"/>


 private async Task TaskComplete(Setask task, string state)
    {
      // do some tasks
    }
```

I get the following error. too many characters in literals. I am trying to pass a string in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You are formatting your OnClick wrongly it should be

```
<MudIconButton  Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.SwipeRight" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Color="Color.Primary" Size="Size.Small" OnClick=@(()=>TaskComplete(task,"InProgress"))/>
```